# Problems reading MySQL database in Java

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

I'm developing an online game with PHP + MySQL and Java to make the server.

At the moment is working great but I've one annoying problem. I have a simple function that reads some data from the database

```
public static String loadWeapon(int playerID) {
    query = "SELECT * FROM players WHERE playerID=" + playerID;
    try {
        ResultSet result = query(query);
        while(result.next()) {
            return result.getString("weapon");
        }
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return null;
}
```

```
public static synchronized ResultSet query(String query) throws SQLException {
    //create a new statment to execute the query
    Statement statment = connection.createStatement();
    //Execute the query
    ResultSet result = statment.executeQuery(query);
    //Wait a bit (If the query is too long...
    statment.setQueryTimeout(300);
    //And return the result
    return result;
}
```

The function works perfectly, now imagine that we open the server and we read the database and the player have a "sword" as weapon but he buys a new one in the shop, the database update it correctly and in the server. I run again that function but returns the first value all the time unless I restart the server. I did the same with other functions but never had this problem, does Java have something like a cache that throws this problem?

Comment: You "return" inside the "while" loop. What should it be doing instead?

Comment: Just put on paper the data and process your algorithm by hand. You'll see the obvious.

Comment: Moreover, `ResultSet` requires an open connection. You cannot just return `ResultSet` from a method (it is also not serializable). Use a different collection to store the result and return the collection instead. Do you really need `synchronized` on the `query()` method?

Comment: but if the value of the database changes why it reads the old one again?

Answer (score 0):

Ensure that MySQLs internal Cache is not used. You can do this by adding `SQL_NO_CACHE`:

```
SELECT SQL_NO_CACHE * FROM players WHERE playerID= ...
```